# Can an Objective c interface have more than one implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface

Can a Objective c interface have more than one implementation? Example I could have a interface but 2 implementations one where i use an arrays or another where I use a stack..etc to implement it.

If so how do you call it / syntax?

Comment: How about using "Protocols" ? It's closer to java/c# interfaces.which is what I want?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Objective-C has the concept of a *Protocol*, which is the specification of an interface.  Through *Protocols*, Objective-C fully supports multiple inheritance of specification (but not implementation).  So, a bit confusingly, the @interface syntax actually defines the class (implementation), which only supports single inheritance, but can specify the implementation of many / multiple inheritance of *Protocols*, or specifications of interfaces.  In the end, this is very similar in nature to Java.

For example:

```
@protocol SomeInterface
- (void)interfaceMethod1;
- (void)interfaceMethod2;
@end

@interface SomeClass:NSObject <SomeInterface>
@end 

@interface AnotherClass:NSObject <SomeInterface>
@end
```

Instances of either `SomeClass` or `AnotherClass` both claim that they provide the implementation required for the `SomeInterface` *protocol*.

Objective-C is dynamically typed and doesn't require that the object actually specify the message being sent to it.  In other words, you can indiscriminately call any method you would like on `SomeClass`, whether it is specified in it's *interface* or any of its *protocols* or **not** (not that this would necessarily be a productive or positive thing to do).

Therefore, all of the following would compile (although with warnings) and run fine, although the messages / methods without implementation is basically a no op in this case.  Objective-C has a fairly complicated (and very cool) process of handling method calling / forwarding that is a bit beyond the scope of this question.

```
SomeClass * someObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init;
[someObject someUnspecifiedMethod];  // Compiles with warning - no op
[someObject interfaceMethod1];
```

If you wish to define something that can be any class (*@interface*) type but implements a specific interface (*@protocol*), you can use something like this:

```
id <SomeInterface> obj;
```

`obj` could hold either a `SomeClass` or `AnotherClass` object.

Comment: You're right... I answered a much more "base" question (and not really the one the OP was asking)...  after re-reading, I can see the OP was probably looking for something more in line with your answer / abstract factories / class clusters.

Answer (score 25):

Perhaps you should try Cocoa pattern called [Class Cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html). To start using it you need to create public class called `SomeClass` and two private subclasses `SomeArrayClass` and `SomeStackClass`. When you need to use stack your public class constructor will create instance of `SomeStackClass` and will return it as publicly available instance of `SomeClass`.

Comment: This is exactly the pattern you want to use.

Comment: How about using "Protocols" ?  It's closer to java/c# interfaces.which is what I want.

Answer (score 20):

(If you give this a vote, please give Roman a vote -- his answer was first, is correct, just lacked an example).

You are talking about a **[Class Cluster](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html)**.  For an example, look at the **NSString** class.

There is NSString:

```
@interface NSString : NSObject
```

And NSMutableString:

```
@interface NSMutableString : NSString
```

Both of which declare an *extremely small set of methods in the core class's declaration*.   If you were to subclass NSString to implement your own string class, *you would only need to implement those core methods*.   ***All other methods implemented in NSString are implemented in terms of those core methods***.  And, likewise, the mutation methods are implemented using the primitive methods declared in the core of NSMutableString.

Now, obviously, implementing all mutability via `- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)aString` (the one core method) would be grossly inefficient.  Thus, at runtime, you'll note that *you never actually have an instance of NSString or NSMutableString*, but only instances of subclasses (which, actually, aren't really subclasses... but they might as well be in the context of this discussion).

And those subclasses -- the implementation class used at runtime -- overrides almost all of the methods of NSString and NSMutableString to provide highly optimized implementations of the specific operations.

So, you would do something like:

```
@interface MyAbstractClass : NSObject
... declare factory methods here ...
... declare core methods here ...
@end

@interface MyAbstractClass(AdditionalFunctionality)
... declare convenience here ...
@end
```

Then, in the implementation, implement all of the core methods as `@throw @"Must use subclass"` and all `AdditionalFunctionality` methods in terms of the core methods.

This could be entirely private -- not in a header at all, even:

@interface MyStackClass : MyAbstractClass
   @end

@implementation MyStackClass
   ... implement the core methods and override the additionalfunctionality methods that need optimization ...
   @end

Repeat for your additional types of classes.   Then, implement factory methods on MyAbstractClass that return instances of the subclasses, as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You mean for example like this:

```
@interface MasterViewController : 
  UIViewController <GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate, 
                    GKSessionDelegate,
                    UITextFieldDelegate,
                    UITableViewDelegate,
                    AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {
}
```

Comment: Or do you actually mean more that one @implementation/@end block?

Comment: Found this looking for way to declare multiple delegates with out creating separate classes and implementations. This worked perfectly.Thanks 2 years later.